# Is [1,2] in (1, [1, 2], 2) implemented in C details as a pointer?

Tags: python

Reference to the shallow copy

```
In [2]: nested_tuple = (1, [1, 2], 2)                                           

In [3]: dup_nested_tuple = tuple(nested_tuple)                                  

In [4]: dup_nested_tuple                                                        
Out[4]: (1, [1, 2], 2)

In [5]: dup_nested_tuple[1][1] = 100                                            

In [6]: nested_tuple                                                            
Out[6]: (1, [1, 100], 2)
```

Is the  inside list of [1,2] implemented in C details as a pointer?

Comment: A tuple holds references to objects, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Are you asking how the underlying implementation of python interpreter manages the memory of the list? And are you assuming that your python interpreter is written in C language?

Comment: yes, it is written in C. @KamilCuk